# Midi playback in Java

Tags: java, midi, playback

I a complete novice to midi.  I'm trying to play a midi file from within a Java application.  The sample file I'm using sounds just as I expect it to when played in Media Player or any of a number of player programs.  However, when I play it in my application, the sound is louder and much tinner--both of which I could probably live with--but it also has an echo-effect, almost like it's being played by two instruments slightly out of synch with each other.

The code I'm using is:

```
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.Sequencer;

public MidiPlayer( String path )
{

    InputStream is = null;

    try
    {
        Sequencer sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();
        is = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( new File( path ) ) );
        sequencer.setSequence(is);
        sequencer.start();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        logger.debug( e.getMessage() );
    }
    finally
    {
        try
        {
            is.close();
        }
        catch ( Exception e ){}
    }
}
```

Can anyone provide advice on how I can address this, or point me to a site that explains (in terms a novice will understand) how to address it?

Comment: Are you instantiating two `MidiPlayer` instances? How are you calling this? Also, why is **all** of your logic in the constructor?

Comment: No, I'm not instantiating two of them.  There's one call of "new MidiPlayer()" in response to a button press.  The code is in the constructor because I'm just trying to get the concept working. I'll refactor code later.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Upload the MIDI track and hot-link to it from the code. BTW - is it just that MIDI file, or any MIDI file?

Comment: Considering you’re closing the InputStream right after starting playback, I’m amazed you hear anything at all.  Are you sure this is really the code you’re running?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure.  Breakpoints hit just fine.  It's a 2 second clip and easily buffered.